# Page with Arguments

Tags: views, 7, theming, uri

I have a basic page  named as news.

Now i have created a two blocks  from view in page news

**Block 1  is block of taxonomy**

**Block 2 is having Contextual Filter with term id**

I have assigned these block to news page 
as

**news**

**news/***

Now when i am accessing

example.com/news 
only Block 1 is coming which is fine

when i am accessing

example.com/news/1

Block1 is coming and 
an error

**Requested page could not found**

I want block 2

How to do this [image]

Please

Thanks

Comment: Check your settings for the contextual filter, specifically the validation settings. Are you sure you have a taxonomy term with id 1? Check the taxonomy term override view for reference.

Comment: yes, still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block views don't automatically pull in contextual filter values from the URL.

So to make it work you need to configure the "When the filter value is NOT available" setting to be "Provide default value".

Then you get some more options appearing below, where in the "Type" field you can select "Taxonomy term ID from URL".

Then configure the other settings as required.

**[EDIT]**
Note that term ID from URL only works from either a node page (node/NID) or a taxonomy term page (taxonomy/term/TID) or an aliased path for one of the pages.

If you want o do it with some other random page use the "Raw value from URL" option for the "When the filter value is NOT available" setting, then select the position in the URL that your parameter is (in your case 2).

Comment: i have done this, i have attached screenshot. still not working

Comment: Your screenshot says you are using the "Load default filter from term page" option. Is your news page a taxonomy term listing page (is it an alias of /taxonomy/term/TID)?

Comment: Edited my answer with info about "Raw value from URL" option.